# Is it possible to override files from android sdk?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

For example i want customize BluetoothGatt class. Is it possible to create android.bluetooth package and put own version of this class?

BluetoothGatt uses android interface files shown in [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e2d281/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java). Can i access these files and use it in own version of BluetoothGatt?

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as you match the package and class name, when you reference it in your code, you will be able invoke your custom behaviour / modified contract

Answer (score 0):

Android classes are simply Java. You can modify the support SDK, as it is simply a Java file. However, this is only applying to your app, or it would be possible for apps to change the entire SDK, which is defeating the point of sandboxing. If you want to extend the class, that is done just the same as in Java, as the class is just Java. However, this specific class is final, so you can't, at least not without hacks. However, the support library is usually a wrapper, so you may as well write your own. If the reason you want to do this is to access a private method, use reflection!

EDIT: To pedantically answer your question, you have already accessed said files, and copy-and-paste is always your friend!

Hope I helped!

Comment: How can i access android .aidl files? For example BluetoothGatt uses IBluetoothGatt.aidl file. Can i copy the file from google soruces and put in android.bluetooth package in app?

Comment: As mentioned, usually hardware interface classes are restricted, and will not work in your app. Unless you have the manufacturer's certificate, or root access, I do not believe this is possible. Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Copying the AIDL file will not work, at least not without a lot of hacking. Please read https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html